# How to show Empty/Blank cell in TableView Objective C iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

if the array is empty means tableview has no data then it should display blank cell in my case it not display blank cell ! My tableview separator is Default And I have attached DataSource And Delegate of Tableview!!

I have check this two lines is not in my code

```
1. self.tableView.tableFooterView.frame = CGRectZero;
2. self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

But it display this if there is no data

[image]

And in this case I want this types of empty or blank cell in TableView !

[image]

Comment: What do you return in `numberOfRows(in section:)`?  You will need to return 1 in the case where your array is empty and return an appropriate, empty, cell in `cellForRow`

Comment: it return my array.count so I think array is empty so it return 0 or nil , and I also check with return 1 but it still not working for me Paulw !!

Comment: You need to return 1 and then check if the array is empty in `cellForRow` and return the required cell. If you are returning 1 and returning an appropriate cell are you sure your tableview is actually appearing? Have you set its constraints correctly?

Comment: Yes Constraints is Perfect !! wait I will do in cellForRow that you tell me ! thank you

Comment: Hii, I try your solution and return cell but it not visible in tableview but I check in Debug View Hierarchy there it shows empty cell !! Now what should i do ?

Comment: Hey Paulw, it's Working Thank You so much for your help !!